# What does this code (from a Mozilla Add-on tutorial) do?

Tags: javascript, mozilla, firefox-addon

```
var Helloworld = {
  onLoad: function() {
    // initialization code
    this.initialized = true;
  },

  onMenuItemCommand: function() {
    window.open("chrome://helloworld/content/hello.xul", "", "chrome");
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load", function(e) { Helloworld.onLoad(e); }, false);
```

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Getting_started_with_extension_development

I don't understand the `function(e) { Helloworld.onLoad(e);` part. I think it passes an event parameter `e` to the onLoad function, but the onLoad function doesn't have `onLoad: function(e) {}` to receive `e`, so what's going on?

Comment: A function can ignore arguments passed to it.

Comment: Everyone, by the way, what is the name of "onLoad:"? It's not a variable, because it's not "var OnLoad="!

Comment: It is an example of defining an object's properties using JSON notation.

Comment: onLoad is a property on the HelloWorld object. Nit-picking: that's not "JSON notation", that's "JavaScript object literal notation". JSON is restricted to data only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just defines an **anonymous function**: the said function will will be called when the event `load` is triggered.

Note that in JavaScript, the function declaration isn't strict. One can call a function with parameters even if the declaration doesn't explicitly show such. In other words, **there is no such thing as a "function signature"** (like in Java, C++ etc.). The JavaScript interpreter will only call the "hasmethod" method on the object to determine if "method X" is implemented.

```
var Helloworld = {

  // parameters can be sent to "onload" but they will be ignored.
  onLoad: function() {
    // initialization code
    this.initialized = true;
  },

  onMenuItemCommand: function() {
    window.open("chrome://helloworld/content/hello.xul", "", "chrome");
  }
};

// attach an event handler to the event "load".  Pass the event variable "e"
// even though the receiving function will ignore it. 
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) { Helloworld.onLoad(e); }, false);
```

Comment: jldupont. can you please answer my last question in the question comments too? thanks!

Comment: @Delirium: JS is not like Java: you don't need to declare strictly a function. JS will look for the method "onLoad" on the object "Helloworld" that's all. It does not look for method "onLoad(e)" i.e. JS doesn't care about "function signatures".

Answer (score 0):

You can change the onLoad if you want to have a parameter, it's just an example onLoad. It's JavaScript, after all, not C/C++ etc.